# How to set up env variables in gitlab-ci.yaml?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

My gitlab ci-cd config file uses many  env variables. To set them, I use gitlab ci-cd secret variables.

For example, dev deploy-part:

```
- echo "====== Deploy to dev server ======"
# Add target server`s secret key
- apk add git openssh bash
- mkdir ~/.ssh
- echo $DEV_SERVER_SECRET_KEY_BASE_64 | base64 -d > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- chmod 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
- echo "Test ssh connection for"
- echo "$DEV_SERVER_USER@$DEV_SERVER_HOST"
- ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T "$DEV_SERVER_USER@$DEV_SERVER_HOST"
# Delploy
- echo "Setup target server directories"
- TARGET_SERVER_HOST=$DEV_SERVER_HOST TARGET_SERVER_USER=$DEV_SERVER_USER TARGET_SERVER_APP_FOLDER=$DEV_SERVER_APP_FOLDER pm2 deploy pm2.config.js dev setup 2>&1 || true
- echo "make deploy"
- TARGET_SERVER_HOST=$DEV_SERVER_HOST TARGET_SERVER_USER=$DEV_SERVER_USER TARGET_SERVER_APP_FOLDER=$DEV_SERVER_APP_FOLDER pm2 deploy pm2.config.js dev
```

I have 5 repositories in project and 3 servers (dev, preprod, prod). So I must manage many variables. Manage all them using gitlab ci-cd secret variables it's very hurt. I can't see it, change it - only delete and create. I agree to use it for secret ssh keys, but it's not suitable for specifying the names of folders, hosts, etc.

Is there some other way to provide variables to ci-cd script?

Comment: Did you figure out a way to pass GitLab ENV to the scripts (via process.env or some other method)?

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom variables in quite a few ways:

**I. using GUI:**

- [per project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#add-a-cicd-variable-to-a-project)
- [per group of projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#add-a-cicd-variable-to-a-group)
- [per Gitlab instance (for all projects and groups)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#add-a-cicd-variable-to-an-instance)

**II.** **using .gitlab-ci.yml file**:

*You can use the **variables** keyword in a job or at the top level of the .gitlab-ci.yml file. If the variable is at the top level, it’s globally available and all jobs can use it. If it’s defined in a job, only that job can use it.*

```
variables:
  TEST_VAR: "All jobs can use this variable's value"

job1:
  variables:
    TEST_VAR_JOB: "Only job1 can use this variable's value"
  script:
    - echo "$TEST_VAR" and "$TEST_VAR_JOB"
```

Make sure to store only non-sensitive variables in your .gitlab-ci.yaml file

Check the [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) for more information and examples.